# How do I make it so that a command only runs when I'm at a certain position

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make it so that if someone goes to a certain coordinate, it will trigger a boss fight.

I have a chain of commands set up to do this, but it can only activate when I pull a lever. I want to make it so that the chain is only run if the player is at the coordinates, but for some reason the following doesn't work as expected:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=-519.5,y=141,z=-258.5] run ...
```

The command I put after run just runs even if I'm not at the specified coordinates. Does anyone know how to make this work? I looked up how `/execute` works but I actually can't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that with your selector, you're only moving the starting point at which the selector starts looking for players, and you didn't actually limit the area it'll search in.

For that you can either use `distance` (to create a spherical selection, based on feet position) or `dx/dy/dz` (to create a cuboid selection based on hitbox overlap).

In your case, assuming you want to know when a player is inside the block you mention, your selector should look like this:

```
@a[x=-519.0,y=141.0,z=-258.0,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0]
```

Read more about target selectors here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors